# Show gift card amount on Magento checkout confirmation

Tags: magento, checkout

Actually i retrieve the order details on my checkout confirmation with

```
$order_details = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
```

and show the discount at checkout confirmation with

```
$discount_amount = $order_details->_data["discount_amount"];
```

but when i want to show gift card with

```
$giftcard_amount = $order_details->_data["giftcard_amount"];
```

its not showing, actually whats wrong with it,Thanks

Comment: try to print `$order_details->getData();` and check if the `giftcard_amount` value exists.

Comment: i found it [gift_cards] => Array
        (
            [15] => AW_Giftcard_Model_Quote_Giftcard Object @Slimshadddyyy

Comment: you need to retrieve the giftcard_amount from Giftcard Object